# completion handler to finish tasks before running another

Tags: swift, completionhandler

I'm really tying myself up in a knot here getting very confused with how to perform tasks in the order i want them to happen.

i have function to build an array from server data and return a result which is the array.  - this works fine and does return the result.

upon the completion of this happening (twice) i want to run another function. for some reason at the moment i am trying to embed these functions in another function with a completion block that will return true once these 2 have completed and returned data, but the way I'm trying this its returning the result before the function has completed.

```
func getCollectionArrays(_ block: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {

    var resultPack: Bool!
    var resultPart: Bool!

        BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: "Pack", sender: self, completeBlock: { (result) in

            if result != nil {

                resultPack = true
            }

        })

                BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: "Part", sender: self, completeBlock: { (result) in

                    if result != nil {

                        resultPart = true
                    }

                })

    // this is returning nil because there isn't enough time for "BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery" to run
    if resultPack == true && resultPart == true {

        block!(true)

    }

}
```

Comment: FYI - `block!(true)` will crash if `block` is `nil`. Don't force unwrap an optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the next step *into* the preceding closure. Keep nesting. Like so:

```
func getCollectionArrays(_ block: ((Bool) -> Void)? = nil) {
    var resultPack: Bool!
    var resultPart: Bool!
    BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: "Pack", sender: self, completeBlock: { (result) in
        if result != nil {
            resultPack = true
        }
        // next step, nested in this closure
        BuildArray.buildArrayFromQuery(queryForCollection: "Part", sender: self, completeBlock: { (result) in
            if result != nil {
                resultPart = true
            }
            // next step, nested in _this_ closure
            if resultPack == true && resultPart == true {
                block!(true)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: for some reason i thought that repetitive nesting was a bad idea

Comment: By no means. GCD nesting often goes many levels deep (switch to a background thread, then to the main thread...). Basically, when things are _asynchronous_, such nesting is the only way to make things happen in the order you want. That is what asynchronous _means_.

Comment: Do not use `block!`. Your code will crash if `block` is `nil` (which is the default).

Comment: Yep, use `block?()`.

Comment: Agreed, that point was made already in the comments on the question. But the focus of my answer was order and nesting, no more.

Comment: @Pippo - Regarding nesting, yes it can become unwieldy if you do it too many times (e.g. imagine you had a dozen levels of more nested calls ... that would be crazy). But you just separate them into different methods and it keeps it clean. Or you can use promises/futures (like PromiseKit or RXPromise). Or you can use operations with dependencies. But with just two levels of nesting, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for follow up info Rob.