# How to make a geocoding function that runs asynchronously finish before subsequent code?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, swiftui

I have a forward geocoding function that is called inside of a function:

```
class AnnotationsVM: ObservableObject {

    @ObservedObject var VModel: ViewModel

    func addNextAnnotation(address: String) {
        self.VModel.fetchCoords(address: address)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
            //Without the asyncAfter, this code runs before the fetchCoords() function is run.
        }
    }
}
```

And the definition of the fetchCoords function is the following:

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published lat: Double?
    @Published lon: Double?

    func fetchCoords(address: String){
        var latitude: Double? = 0.0
        var longitude: Double? = 0.0
        self.getLocation(from: address) { coordinates in
            self.location = coordinates // Assign to a local variable for further processing
            self.lon = coordinates?.longitude
            self.lat = coordinates?.latitude
        }
    }
}
```

My question is, is there a more efficient way to do the DispatchQueue rather than just tacking on an arbitrary time (I used 0.1 seconds but would prefer for that code to run as soon as fetchCoords has run).

Comment: Is `getLocation` an async function?

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure...If I add print statements inside the completion handler and print statements after the function is called in the addNextAnnotation function, it prints the lines after the fetchCoords call before the other ones

Comment: Right. So, this is definitely NOT the way to do this. It's not just not efficient - it's hacky and brittle, since you don't have any guarantees of how long an async request for coordinates would take. There are multiple patterns to use here, for example with a completion handler of your own (i.e. `fetchCoords` could take a completion handler parameter that you would invoke from within the completion handler of `getLocation`

Comment: What would that completion handler look like?

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/

Comment: And see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/41476467/341994

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you just waiting for some arbitrary time to *hope* that the data is available is a very hacky and brittle approach.

There are numerous patterns to handle async behavior, but one thing you could do here is to pass a completion handler, that would be invoked when the `fetchCoords` completes.

So, let's say that this completion handler accepts the coordinates (for simplicity, I'll use 2 Doubles):

```
func fetchCoords(address: String, completion: @escaping (Double, Double) -> Void){
   self.getLocation(from: address) { coordinates in

      self.location = coordinates

      if let lat = coordinates?latitude, let lon = coordinates?longitude {
          completion(lat, lon)
      }
}
```

```
func addNextAnnotation(address: String) {
   self.VModel.fetchCoords(address: address) { lat, lon in
      // do something with lat and long
   }
}
```

Of course, this is just a conceptual approach (for example, it doesn't handle errors), but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: Wow, completion handlers seem like they are going to be super helpful in a bunch of situations...thanks man